# Web-scraping with requests python library- Key error

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can you sort this code out please?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cse.lk/api/aspi"

data = requests.post(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["reqAspi"])

print(df)
```

This says there is a KeyError: 'reqAspi'

Can anyone help me to find the key for this api link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to chrome developer mode and refresh your site copy paste company name and see from image you can uderstand very well. (In Left hand side you can see!)

Image:
[image]

You have selected wrong key from json data it should be `main_data['reqASPIIndices']` this.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cse.lk/api/aspi"

req= requests.post(url)
main_data=req.json()
data=main_data['reqASPIIndices']
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
id  name    symbol  lastTradedTime  price   turnover    sharevolume tradevolume change  changePercentage
0   328 CIC HOLDINGS PLC    CIC.X0000   1.628845e+12    39.50   939905.2    23661.0 50.0    0.4 1.023018
1   357 SMB LEASING PLC SEMB.X0000  1.628845e+12    0.20 1380198.4  6895960.0   128.0   0.0 0.000000
.....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me where to find that key? @Bhavya Parikh

Comment: just priny main_data you can find first key and take it as used that data for `df` if possible you can mark answer as or upvote for better understanding

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find that from the link provided? Under developer mode?

Comment: i am not able to open this URL in chrome so if you have main URL i can help!

Comment: Sorry. Here it is https://www.cse.lk/pages/indices/indices.component.html

Comment: And can you tell me how this python code works please? Thank you very much for the support...

Comment: @tchar first he was facing problem with key error thing okay and i am describing my answer

Answer (score 0):

To solve KeyError, the response is returning the data as

```
{'reqASPIIndices': [{'id': 328, 'name': 'CIC HOLDINGS PLC', 'symbol': 'CIC.X0000', 'lastTradedTime': 1 ....
```

So you need to use key - 'reqASPIIndices'

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cse.lk/api/aspi"

data = requests.post(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["reqASPIIndices"])

print(df)
```